# Mikrotik hotspot issue - login page not loading

Tags: configuration, wifi, login, mikrotik

I've configured a hotspot on a Mikrotik CCR1036-12G (OS 6.47.4), but after the device connects to the wifi and asks to authenticate in the network, the login page remains loading for a while and returns an error page with `net:ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. The hotspot worked perfectly already, but suddently stopped.

[image: smartphone login page error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem wasn't on Mikrotik configuration, that was OK. The problem was on the wifi configuration, in Unifi solution:

i) In the network configuration, the used network was marked as "Guest". I changed to "corporate".

ii) In the wireless configuration, there was enabled the "Gest Policy" option. I disabled it.

Both options (or maybe just one - the guest policy, I think) was resulting in the described problem because I didn't configure the guest portal in the Unifi solution. My fault... :´/

Well, we learn from our mistakes too...